# How to handle button input in microsoft bot framework v4, using adaptive cards

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

i have an adaptive card which has 3 options:
1. shopping
2. date
3. year

these are 3 submit buttons in adaptive card layout.
the flow is working fine if we click on the button, whereas if we type in the same value it doesn't respond properly

requesting help.

Comment: Can you share your code when you prompt for the input and then process it? I know if you collect a value via entity recognition vs. button press it shows up in step.result instead of step.result.value (in waterfall dialog), not sure if you are dealing with a similar issue here.

Comment: Are you still working on this? (Since there are more than two people in this thread, you will have to @ mention me so I see your reply)